Old movie with man and girlfriend transforming into tigers
About 20 years ago when I was a kid I watched a scary movie (I think it was German, but I'm not sure) in which a man and his girlfriend transformed into tigers (or maybe werewolves or something similar) at nights and killed others. During the day when they were human, their real animal appearance could be seen when looked in the mirror. Does anyone know the name of the movie?

Sounds like bollywood film Junoon (1992 film) but you expecting it to be German.

It was definitely either a European or an American movie, leaning more toward European and German.

"or maybe werewolves or something similar" I'm afraid this makes your question extremely vague. What language was it in? Was it from the 90s? What do they look like in their monster form? This could be Sleepwalkers from 1992 [werecat couple; the mirror thing] but right now it could be thousands of other movies. Please help us narrow it down.

As walt said there are so many film on Were animals. So please narrow it down with as much detail you have.

@Walt I can't be any less vague since I was a little kid when I watched it. I saw Sleepwalkers trailer and it might be the one (There was a scissors scene in trailer and I remember the movie I watched had a scary scissors scene). I'll watch the movie and let you know. Thanks a lot.

Glad to help, but a scary scissor scene is a good example of a detail that might help us and what we mean by adding any detail to ID questions, even if it seems minor. We welcome these details.

If the were/cat people were afraid of cats and they could turn invisible (except to cats) then it was almost certainly Sleepwalkers as Walt pointed out.

@Walt I watched the movie. Sleepwalkers was the one. Thanks.

I am pretty sure it's "Cat People" with Nastassja Kinski! She is of german origin and the movie is about people turning into panthers.

@EIDuderino: Thanks very much. I'll watch it and see if this is the one. I was a little kid when I watched it and I was not sure by just looking at short clips.
